# How can i convert my react app from English to Arabic language with the help of a toggle button

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I need my React app to convert all the web content from English to the Arabic language. It should be done with the help of a toggle button of converting English to Arabic.

Comment: go through this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-translate-component

Comment: Or this https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit/tutorials/how-to-translate-your-react-app-with-react-i18next

Comment: but when you convert the web content from english to arabic you must change the layout from left to right

Answer (score 0):

you can create json file like this.

```js
const LANG = {
  "DE": {
      hello: 'Hallo'
   },
   "EN": {
      hello: 'Hello'
   },
   "FA": {
   hello: "سلام"
   }
}


let currnetLang = "EN";


const handleLang = () => {
 currnetLang = ( currnetLang === "EN") ? "DE" : "EN";
}

const setLang = lang => {
  currnetLang = lang;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick={handleLang}>Toggle Lang</button>
<button type="button" onClick={setLang} name="EN">EN</button>
<button type="button" onClick={setLang} name="FA">FA</button>
<button type="button" onClick={setLang} name="DE">DE</button>


<p>Current Language is {LANG[currnetLang]}</p>
<p>{LANG[currnetLang].hello} username </p>
```